# QR factorization: floating-point issues

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I've implemented QR factorization based on Householder reflections (for the purposes of computing the OLS fit). Mathematically, the $R$ matrix is upper triangular. However, due to floating-point issues I typically end up with small non-zero entries below the diagonal.

What should I do with them - leave alone or set to zero, and why?

For example, the following input:

```
[[ 1  1 10]
 [ 3  3  5]
 [ 2  4 -6]
 [ 1 10  8]]
```

produces the following $R$ matrix:

```
[[ -3.87298335e+00  -7.22956891e+00  -5.42217668e+00]
 [ -8.88178420e-16   8.58681159e+00   4.86793026e+00]
 [ -4.44089210e-16  -3.33066907e-16   1.31111882e+01]]
```

Note the non-zeros below the main diagonal. For comparison, both `numpy` and `R` return exact zeros, so I am wondering if there are reasons for me to do the same.

Comment: This is a little off-topic, but I would urge you to consider whether you really want to be doing this in the first place. If you are implementing this QR  factorization, e.g., as a project in a course on numerical methods, that is fine and good. For (almost) *any* other reason, you should strongly consider using a standard numerical linear algebra package. For example, `numpy`, $R$ and MATLAB are all using LAPACK under the hood.

Comment: To echo @cardinal, much intensive research has been put into optimally implementing QR decomposition for various computing environments via LAPACK; unless you already are competent in numerical linear algebra and believe you can do better than LAPACK, you should stick to a canned routine.

Comment: This is both a learning exercise and a stepping stone towards building some highly-specialized tools for which no suitable pre-canned solutions exist.

Comment: @aix Even if your routine is highly specialized, you should be able to link to LAPACK. That is unless there are licensing restrictions of some sort you have to deal with.

Comment: @JWM: While we're on the subject, please could you point me to a standard LAPACK routine that would update a QR factorization with new rows? I need to be able to call it from `numpy` and can't compile anything (i.e. it has to be callable from pure Python/numpy). I can't for the life of me find anything... Thanks!

Comment: @aix I have used `numpy` very little, but check out this link: [http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users](http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users). Near the bottom of the table there is an example of a QR decomposition. I believe `numpy` uses LAPACK.

Comment: @JWM: Thanks for the link. Sadly, there's nothing on that page about *updating* a factorization with new rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, LAPACK does not support QR updating/downdating; Daniel Kressner however has written (FORTRAN) routines for doing this, see [here](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~kressner/qrupdate.php).

Answer (score 4):

It's safe to ignore those tiny entries, as long as they are less than some quantity like "norm of the matrix times machine epsilon". FWIW, if you'll be doing backsubstitution with the triangular matrix you now have, the routine is not supposed to access those subdiagonal entries anyway.

Comment: Indeed, the subdiagonal entries aren't even ***stored*** in any of the standard implementations of a $QR$ decomposition.

Comment: @cardinal: right, for purposes of compactness, one often stores the (scaled) Householder transformations for forming $\mathbf Q$ where the zeroes of the triangular matrix ought to be.